# How to use csproj files created with dotnet migrate in Visual Stuidio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, csproj

I created a c# (.net core) project in Visual Studio to be able to run it on Linux. Then I setup my linux box to run .net core apps and found out that dotnet restore didnt work because of xproj files but luckyly I could run dotnet migrate that created a csproj files instead and so I was able to build and run on Linux. 
Now I want to make some changes using Visual Studio 2015 and I discovered that it doesnt recognize that particular format of csproj file for the project.
How can I support both Windows and Linux using one solution file and proper csproj files?

Comment: use visual studio 2017

Comment: Install VS 2017 RC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csproj files created with `dotnet migrate` are only supported using the [.NET Core Tools RC3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/) or newer.

Currently the only version of Visual Studio that supports that toolset is the Visual Studio 2017 release candidate, Visual Studio 2015 only supports up to the .NET Core Tools RC2.

When installing Visual Studio 2017 be sure to check the following box in the "Other Toolsets" section to include the latest release of the tools in the install

[image]

Comment: why xproj files are not supported anymore instead? I have to install 12GB just for that?

Comment: The main reason the change was done was so support for MSBuild could be used again, MSBuild requires XML files instead of JSON so they had to change the format. [I am sure such a large change was not done lightly](http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj). Also the 12GB is because I was also installing many other features I also needed in my development, if you only install the tools using Community Edition instead of Enterprise it only requires 4.7GB

Comment: Also, if you are removing 2015 when you are upgrading to 2017 you have to think of the net change in hard drive space. the total amount of space used will likey just stay the same after upgrading. However I would wait till 2017 is out of RC to do that (It releases [March 7th on the 20th anniversary of Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/02/09/visual-studio-2017-launch-event-and-20th-anniversary/))

Comment: @PaoloV in year 2017 where we count TB for storage, it would be surprising that someone has a concern of just a few GB. You can just choose to install .NET Core related bits though, which can save several GB.

Comment: @LexLi not a concern about space (I have more than 1TB free on my 2 HDs..), I was just sarcastic.. also I said 12Gb because I was already installing VS2017 when writing the question as it took mw a while to discovered it too and nowhere it's really clear!! Anyway move to VS 2017 was already scheduled but I'd have preferred waiting for release in 2 weeks

Answer (score 2):

It is a smart move for Microsoft to dump project.json and move back to the existing MSBuild ecosystem, whether you like it or not, and Visual Studio 2017 is recommended like the other answer said.

But if you do have concerns moving to it, I think you can simply fire up Visual Studio Code,

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet

(Or JetBrains Rider).